# Sort with proxy model

Tags: qt, filtering, qtableview, qregexp, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a little question.

I'm using QTableView with simple text items, row selection and QSortFilterProxyModel model.
I reimplemented this:

```
void MyTableView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model)
{
  assert(model);

  m_proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
  QTableView::setModel(m_proxyModel);
}
```

For example, my table contains numbers and it has 3 rows. If i'll set any value to my filter (in pop-up box f.e.) i want to show in my table only row with this number:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

Set value: 5

4 5 6

I tried this:

```
m_proxyModel->setFilterRegExp("5");
m_proxyModel->setFilterKeyColumn(column); //column = 1 for my example
```

But nothing changed. So help me, how i must use this proxy model correctly?

Sorry for my bad English.

**EDIT:**

```
void MyTableView::editFilterPattern(int column)
{ 
    QStringList patterns; 
    for (int row = 0; row < model()->rowCount(QModelIndex()); ++row)
        patterns.push_back(model()->data(model()->index(row, column)).toString());
    m_filterEditor->setFilterPatterns(patterns);
    if(m_filterEditor->exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        if(!m_filterEditor->filter())
        {
            m_proxyModel->setFilterRegExp(QString());
            return; 
        }
        m_proxyModel->setFilterRegExp(m_filterEditor->getCurrentFilterPattern());
        m_proxyModel->setFilterKeyColumn(column); 
    }
}

CMyTableFilterEditor::CMyTableFilterEditor(QWidget *parent) :
  QDialog(parent), m_ui(new Ui::CFilterEditor())
{
  m_ui->setupUi(this);

  connect(m_ui->m_buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(accept()));
  connect(m_ui->m_buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()));
}

void CMyTableFilterEditor::setFilterPatterns(const QStringList& patterns)
{
  clearFilterPatterns();
  m_ui->m_comboFilters->addItems(patterns);
}

void CMyTableFilterEditor::clearFilterPatterns()
{
  m_ui->m_comboFilters->clear();
  m_ui->m_comboFilters->addItem(tr("(All)"));
}

QString CMyTableFilterEditor::getCurrentFilterPattern() const
{
  return m_ui->m_comboFilters->currentText();
}

bool CMyTableFilterEditor::filter() const
{
  return m_ui->m_comboFilters->currentIndex() != 0;
}
```

Comment: You should set your proxy model to your view - `setModel(m_proxyModel);`

Comment: Fixed, but nothing changed. If i will set any qstring to filterregexp, it will always clear my table.

Comment: You should provide an example that fully demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Lol .. The problem is that m_filterEditor->getCurrentFilterPattern() returns empty QString o.O It's strange ..

Answer (score 0):

Your `filter()` method must be

```
bool CMyTableFilterEditor::filter() const
{
  return m_ui->m_comboFilters->currentIndex() != -1;
}
```

because `QComboBox::currentIndex()` is `-1` if no item is selected.